# Webview - How to link it to a android app and then work on the operations

Tags: android, html, webview

Got a pretty hectic task for myself here and i'm done with googling it ..

Im presently working on an app that has to take an

1. input , (String )(EditText) from the user end .
2. Use that string and pass it on to a webview , so that the search is done based on this string , (for eg: lets take youtube as an example so the passed content is a Songs name).
3. Once the search has been made the app has to pickup the url of the present search made .... i.e in youtube when we search for something we get the url as 
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS4F49XqLWo" so the app has to store this url .
4. Paste the url onto another site and then Click on some buttons on that site (The major problem part -- how do i get the app to automatically click on buttons on another site ??)

Im just a novice at Android Development , espacially at the html side of it ... so kindly bear with me !!...

Comment: Just direct me to alink , if the question has  been asked previously ...: ) kind of new to stack overflow ...:)

Comment: Not shure if understood you well, but my guess is: forget webView, it will only complicate things. Make everything around textView and editText then, at the end, if really needed, open a webView to show the results.

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted ... : ( .... let me clear things a bit for you ...

Comment: The app is basically for Song downloading .

so as first 

1. Should take input from user . -- Edit text used for that.
2. Should query the songname in youtube . 
3. Once the search is made , We usually get a link like the youtube link i mentioned above .

Comment: 4. Paste this link in a site called KeepVid.com 
5. Click on the downloadbutton on the site.

Comment: Now , 4 and 5 should not be controlled by user , once the song is selected from youtube , it should pass the link of that song directly to site and download the song .... i hope this clears a lot .

Comment: Plus 1 for the explanation. Very understood. Trying now to help figure out a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Mean while cracked a bit of the code  ...

Tested and works ..:)

Comment: Used this to query for the Song -- web.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + songname);

and once we select the song from the youtube ,  i used webview.geturl(); to get the url of the present .

Now the problem is i need to click on a download button on another site  . Can this be made done through code ?? 

This is what bothers me know :/